# UICollectionView Layout Warnings

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

After formatting my main cells to do horizontal scrolling, I have been getting a warning that spams the entire console and just annoys me in general.

I've already tried changing constraints and cell size, but one way or another the warning always appears.

In my feedCell class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3.5)
} //Sets each cell's frame

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
} //Removes spacing between the cells
```

In my mainView class I am using horizontal scroll cells defined by:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height-60)
}
```

I also initialize my menu bar with:

```
private func setupMenuBar() {
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(60)]", views: menuBar)
}
```

I have also set the Navigation Bar to

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

My status bar height is equal to 20 but I don't think that it is the main problem.

Error messages:

```
2019-06-14 19:38:55.755740+0300[71578:4274545] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2019-06-14 19:38:55.756169+0300[71578:4274545] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7faba0f027d0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7faba1047000; frame = (0 0; 414 808); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e7c360>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002074d40>; contentOffset: {0, -50}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {50, 0, 34, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7faba0f027d0>.
2019-06-14 19:38:55.756248+0300[71578:4274545] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: It's not spam if it's helpful information. :-) Have you followed the advice ("Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.")? Have you tried the built-in view debugger in Xcode ("Debug View Hierarchy" button along debugger bar)? Do so and update your question with the details of your findings.

Comment: The thing is, I am unable to find the UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes class/function to make a breakpoint and have next to know knowledge on proper debugger usage that involves more than making breakpoints.

Comment: I would suggest, then, that you invest some time reading about this. The debugger is to a developer as a club is to a baby seal hunter: essential. Give this a read: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/xcode-breakpoint-wizardry/ (the "Symbolic Breakpoints" section is most relevant to your comment, but you really REALLY **REALLY** need a better understanding of debugging).

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the reading material. However, even after adding a symbolic breakpoint -[UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes] the app launches up and functions just fine but the warnings keep popping up

Comment: Edit: I have run the application with the breakpoint formatted differently. The error seems to stem from the ->  0x10ecf5a0c <+0>:  testq  %rdi, %rdi line in the class. What could be a possible fix?
The breakpoint also gets toggled even when I have reduced my cell size

Comment: Fixed the issue by resizing the cells and turning off navigation bar hiding on scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. If anyone is also having this problem, make sure that you are not using UIScreen.main.bounds.height for your cell size and have hidesBarsOnSwipe set on true. This seemed to fix it for me.